# Como passar variável do tipo double através da classe Bundle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Não consigo passar um valor de um textview de uma activity A para a activity B para poder realizar alguns cálculos. Já tentei através do método putExtra passar variável do tipo string e depois converter para double e não consegui e ja tentei também por bundle e também não consegui, apenas consigo passar variáveis do tipo string independente de qual método eu uso, mas não consigo converte-la.
E quando da certo passar as variáveis o botão para realizar os cálculos não funciona e fecha o app. 
O que devo fazer para poder conseguir passar a variavél e poder fazer o cálculo através do botão na Activity B?

Seguem o código que de passagem de string por bundle.

trecho do código Activity A onde o botão chama a Activity B:

```
public void padiola (View v){




    Intent telapad = new Intent(this,Padiola.class);

    Bundle parametros = new Bundle();

    String va = vua.getText().toString();
    String vb = vub.getText().toString();

    parametros.putString("chavea", va);
    parametros.putString("chaveb", vb);

    telapad.putExtras(parametros);

    startActivity(telapad);


}
```

Activity B:

```
TextView qtda, qtdb, alta, altb, vuar, vubr;


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_padiola);

    qtda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtdPadareia);
    qtdb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtdPadbrita);
    alta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altAreia);
    altb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altBrita);
    vuar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.novoVA);
    vubr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.novoVB);

    Intent telapad = getIntent();

    Bundle parametros = telapad.getExtras();

    String va1 = parametros.getString("chavea");
    String vb1 = parametros.getString("chaveb");

    vuar.setText(va1);
    vubr.setText(vb1);

}

public void trintaxquarenta(View v) {

    //Para Areia//

    double s1 = Double.parseDouble(vuar.getText().toString());
    double s2 = Double.parseDouble(vubr.getText().toString());

    double s3 = s1 + s2;

    qtda.setText(Double.toString(s3));

}
```

}

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado no código. O que quer dizer com "não consigo"? Dá algum erro?

Comment: O código descrito acima é de passagem de string, está certo o código. Mas eu preciso de uma variável tipo double para poder fazer os cálculos e eu não estou conseguindo converter a string para double, pois quando clico no botão para executar a soma ele da erro e fecha o app.

Comment: Então é porque o texto que está no EditText não é válido como Double. Veja se o problema não é troca de ponto por virgula, ou vise-versa.

Comment: Mas os valores não estão em EditText, estão armazenados em Text View. Como assim ponto ou virgula ?

Comment: Coloque o erro que dá.

Comment: O erro que da é que o App parou de funcionar, apenas Isso.

Comment: Depois que vse comentou sobre e fui pesquisar e identifiquei que o problema de conversão era que a string estava com virgula e não estava convertendo para double. Consegui através do método replace.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza?!
Como teve dúvidas de onde e quando recuperar os valores na sua activity A, postei o código completo.

> Na sua Activity A:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declarando os campos de valores
    EditText valor1, valor2;
    //Botao para a proxima intent
    Button botaoProximaIntent;
    //valores double para a proxima intent
    double a, b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        valor1 = findViewById(R.id.valor1);
        valor2 = findViewById(R.id.valor2);
        botaoProximaIntent = findViewById(R.id.botaoProximaIntent);
        //click no botao
        botaoProximaIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //faça as validacoes antes de pegar os valores
                //resgate seu double A do editText
                a = Double.parseDouble(valor1.getText().toString());
                //resgate seu double A do editText
                b = Double.parseDouble(valor2.getText().toString());

                //agora temos o valor de a e b, vamos chamar a proxima intent e passar os parametros
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                //declaramos o bundle
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                //parametros do bundle
                params.putDouble("valor1", a);
                params.putDouble("valor2", b);
                intent.putExtras(params);
                //chamamos a proxima intent
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Na sua Activity B, receba os valores:

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);
        //declarando os valores
        double a, b;
        // pegando os parametros intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //validando a intent
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
            //validando se há parametros
            if  (params != null)
            {
                //resgatando os valores na segunda intent
                a = params.getDouble("valor1");
                b = params.getDouble("valor2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu recupero os valores double fora da intent e dentro do médoto de execução do botão ?

Comment: Testei dessa forma que me indicou e não funcionou. Ao clicar no botão na activity A o app esta fechando com erro.

Comment: eu testei antes de te manda, pois geralmente passo pelo putExtra. mas vou editar pra vc conferir como ficou, deve está errando em algo simples.

Comment: Resposta editada @IF12 , veja como ficou o código completo.

Comment: Mas o valor que preciso passar estar setado em text view e não é um edit text ou e a mesma coisa ?

Comment: Da na mesma, troque as declarações de EdtitText para TextView, o restante segue a mesma coisa

Comment: Troquei as declarações e não funcionou de novo. Dá erro no Botão que abre a Activity B. Ele fecha a aplicação.

Comment: poderia posta o erro no logcat? deve esta declarando alguma coisa errada

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.irineufarias.appconcrete, PID: 7797
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                          
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "50,50"

Comment: cara, o erro está ai na exception, vc está colocando 50,50. O certo de double é 50.50

Comment: Sim, quando o valor e mostrado no text view da activity A ele esta com virgula e quando e passado a string para activity B também esta com virgula e não consigo converter para ponto como é em double. Tem o método replace será que ele funciona pra converter virgula para ponto  ?

Comment: @Leonardo Figueiredo, pediu pra te responder: claro que sim, basta vc dar um replace no valor, trocando , por .
String valorFormatado = string.replace(",", ".");

Comment: Consegui. Passei variável tipo string por classe intent sem o bundle e depois converti para double e utilizei o método replace.

Comment: Ficou assim :  Activity B : String va = intent.getStringExtra("chaveA");   e para converter usei Double va1 = Double.parseDouble(va.replace("," , ".")); e por fim para mostrar o valor :  vuar.setText(Double.toString(va1));